# Is there a library available for the SECS/GEM protocol?

Tags: delphi, protocols, delphi-xe2, secs

I have to implement a communication between my app and another PC using the industrial standard protocol [SECS/GEM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SECS/GEM) PV2.

Are there any libraries available that I can use with Delphi?
Google didn't give me any usable results so far, maybe someone has experience with this protocol already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page about [High-Speed SECS Message Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSMS) lists an open source implementation:

[FREESECS, an open source suite of implementations of semiconductor fab communication standards](http://opensecs.sourceforge.net/)

FREESECS components are implemented in C and C++. Currently available are: HSMS (SEMI E37.1) and SECSII (SEMI E5).

Maybe these components can be used with Delphi.